# Passing data between Parent fragment and Child fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm struggling with a communication between 2 or more fragments

My application architecture looks like this:

```
MainActivity (Menu Drawer) 
---->  MealsFragment
---->  ProfileFragment
---->  StatsFragment
---->  SportFragment
---->  ContactUsFragment
```

(By clicking on menu drawer main_container is replaced with selected Fragment)

Earlier, I had single activities instead of fragments but I have read that I need to convert them into Fragments to correctly implement menu drawer (so I did it).
The problem is each of the activities had its own child-activities which were communicating with parents with using onActivityResult. Now I don't know how to do it with fragments.

The scenario is like this:

1. Open MealsFragment from MainActivity (it works)
2. Open AddMealFragment from MealsFragment (with data from MealsFragment), fill the form and then return all information provided there by user to MealsFragment
3. Use received data for further actions

I have already seen posts recommending using settargetFragment() and getTargetFragment() but I don't know how to do it and - what is more important - I don't know how to receive the data afterwards

Comment: it's easier if you have implemented the Navigation graph. have you done that? If so I will share the solution for that.

Comment: I've never heard about it :( Do I need to know this to make my application works properly?

Comment: If you use a navigation graph you can send the data from fragment to fragment as an argument.it will make the work easier. There is always another way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are aware of how to do `Fragment transactions`, i.e. using `Fragment Manager` class to add or remove fragments from the backstack. If you don't know then it's a good idea to learn that first.

Now that you know how to add or remove fragments, passing data among them is a simple thing of all of that in fragment's `Bundle` that you can access in the receiver fragment. Here's an example:

```
class ConversationFragment : Fragment() {
  companion object {
    const val JOB_REQUEST_ID = "jobRequestId"

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(jobRequestId: String) =
      ConversationFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply { putString(JOB_REQUEST_ID, jobRequestId) }
      }
  }
}
```

In order to create `ConversationFragment`, I expose a `newInstance` method that the `FragmentManager` or any other entity can use to create one. However, they would need to pass a `JOB_REQUEST_ID` in order to create one. I simply put this id in a `Bundle` and pass it on to the fragment as its argument. On the receiver side(fragment), you can get a handle to this bundle and retrive the value:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
      jobRequestId = it.getString(JOB_REQUEST_ID)
    }
  }
```